# uib-Pagination won't work for my app?

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I have been practicing an example of pagination using this example [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/01/13/tutorial-for-building-spa-using-angularjs-example/). Everything just works fine except for the pagination part. I have tried several example on internet but couldn't found a solution for this. I'm using the latest one, Though I tried according to the document it still didn't work.

Here's my pagination part:

```
<div>
   <div data-pagination="" data-previous-text="<" data-next-text=">" data-first-text="<<" data-last-text=">>"
    data-on-select-page="pageChanged(page)" data-total-items="totalRecordsCount" data-page="currentPage"
    data-boundary-links="true" class="pagination pagination-sm" data-max-size="5" data-rotate="false" data-items-per-page="10">
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried:

```
<div uib-data-pagination="" data-previous-text="<" data-next-text=">" data-first-text="<<" data-last-text=">>"...
```

What is the latest way of doing this? Sorry I'm new to angularjs.

Comment: I still need help for this anyone interested??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not giving enough context.

First off, use **uib-pagination** which comes with the module **angular-bootstrap**, described at [UI Bootstrap pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination). Use it in HTML like this:

`<uib-pagination
              boundary-links="true"
              direction-links="true"
              rotate="false"
              total-items="totalItems"
              ng-model="currentPage"
              items-per-page="size"
              max-size="5"
              class="pagination-sm"
              ng-change="pageChanged (currentPage)"
              first-text="<<"
              previous-text="<"
              next-text=">"
              last-text=">>">
            </uib-pagination>`